# Finding a path where the function increases the most rapidly

Tags: calculus

> Consider the differentiable function $z = f(x,y)$. Construct a path
> $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ on the graph of $z=f(x,y)$ of
> $\textbf{ steepest ascent}$ that starts at some point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the graph of $z=f(x,y)$

thoughts:

I know $\nabla f$ is a vector that always points in the direction of the steepest ascent of the function $z=f(x,y)$. Initially, at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, the direction of highest increase is $( f_x(x_0,y_0), f_y(x_0,y_0))$. This occurs at the level curve $f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0)$

Let $\gamma(t) = (x,y)$ be such a curve. For this path we want its derivative to be in the direction of the gradient at each level curve. That is ,

$$ \dfrac{ \partial f}{\partial x} (a,b) = \dfrac{d x}{d t} $$

and

$$ \dfrac{ \partial f}{\partial y} (a,b) = \dfrac{d y}{d t} $$

and $\gamma(0) = (x_0,y_0)$. So, solving that system of ODE's will yield such a path.

Is this an efficient approach?

Comment: There is the small problem of "$\gamma:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3$": you must also consider $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}$, $\gamma_z(t)$

Comment: Well, that should be $f(a,b)$ no?

Comment: I think this question may be ill-posed. Besides, for this kind of question, I think about the calculus of variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to solve any ODEs.

Suppose $\nabla f (x_0, y_0) = (a,b)$. As you already know, this is the direction of steepest ascent of $f$.

The parametric equation $t \mapsto (x_0,y_0) + t(a,b)$ is a line in this direction passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$. To get the desired curve, we just need to project this line vertically onto the surface $z=f(x,y)$. This projection sends the point $(x,y)$ to the point $(x,y, f(x,y))$.

Putting everything together, the desired curve is
$$
\gamma(t) = \bigl(x_0 +ta, y_0 +tb, f(x_0+ta, y_0+tb) \bigr)
$$
Note that when $t=0$ this curve “starts” at the point $ \bigl(x_0, y_0, f(x_0,y_0) \bigr)$, not at the point $(x_0, y_0)$. The latter point might not even lie on the surface $z=f(x,y)$, so the statement of the question is somewhat flawed.

Having read the question again, I now see that you might be asking for a curve that’s running in the direction of steepest ascent at **every** point along it’s length, not just at its start point. If so, then you probably do need to solve the ODEs you cited.